# Why is my custom filter causing infinite digestion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters, angularjs-digest

I created a custom filter to break an array of key-value pairs into an object that groups values by the first letter of a particular property. For example

> Input: `[{foo: 'bar'}, {faz: 'baz'}, {boo: 'foo'}]`
>
> Output: `{f: [{foo: bar}, {faz: baz}], b: [{boo, foo}]}`

However this filter seems to be causing an infinite digestion error in Angular.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.arr = [{name: 'foo', def: 'bar'}, {name: 'faz', def: 'baz'}, {name: 'boo', def: 'foo'}]
}]);

app.filter('firstLetterChunks', function() {
    return function(input){
        var chunks={};
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            var firstLetter = input[i].name[0].toUpperCase();
            if(!(chunks.hasOwnProperty(firstLetter))) {
                chunks[firstLetter]=[];
            }
            chunks[firstLetter].push(input[i]);
        }

        return chunks;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    This caused a infdig error. Check your console.
    <div ng-repeat="(firstletter, values) in arr | firstLetterChunks">
      {{firstletter}}
      <hr>
      <div ng-repeat="value in values">
        {{value}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I cant figure out why. From what I've found, this is usually caused by modifying your model in the filter, thus re-triggering the ng-repeat, however I don't think I'm doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because every filter call basically returns a new object, which has a new identity and therefore Angular believes something has changed. This in turn triggers a new digest cycle and this goes on until the 10 digests limit is reached.

I suppose there can be other ways to fix it with the use of caching to store your computed object and keep the filter, but I changed your code to the following which works just the same, but you have to recalculate `chunks` if the array changes:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.arr = [{name: 'foo', def: 'bar'}, {name: 'faz', def: 'baz'}, {name: 'boo', def: 'foo'}];

    function getChunks() {
        var input = $scope.arr;
        var chunks = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            var firstLetter = input[i].name[0].toUpperCase();
            if(!(chunks.hasOwnProperty(firstLetter))) {
                chunks[firstLetter]=[];
            }
            chunks[firstLetter].push(input[i]);
        }

        return chunks;
    }

    $scope.chunks = getChunks();
}]);
```

And change the HTML call to:

```
<div ng-repeat="(firstletter, values) in chunks">
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5z5rax9/1/)